# How to force file replacement on MSI upgrade

Tags: installation, windows-installer, upgrade, installshield

Using Installshield 2010 with a Basic MSI project.

I have several config files that have to be replaced during an upgrade. Since they are config files, they don't have a version.  I believe they aren't replaced during because during the original install, the configs are modified by the installer.  This sets the modified date different than the creation date.  As I understand it the unversioned file has been modified the upgrade won't replace it.

Is there a way to force the replacement ?  I have some bootstrap prerequsites that require a setup.exe so I would rather not modify the .msi in orca.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSI has a concept called Version Lying. (Well, actually it's a hack around MSI's default file versioning rules.) InstallShield's implementation of this is to put a really high number into the File table.  Go through components | files and do a right click properties on the file in question and select always overwrite.

Note: It'll be best if this file is also the key file of it's own component.  Wierd things could happen ( or not happen ) to this file or other files if it's not if you hit the right circumstances. ( See: Component Rules )

Comment: Thanks.  I was using dynamic file linking which doesn't allow me to specify overwriting rules.  Changed to static linking and seems to be behaving how according to my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

RESINSTALLMODE=amus is dangerous because in some cases it may actually downgrade common files to lower versions